# Image conversion to blob format is not working (File Reader - Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, image, blob, filereader

i'm trying to convert an image taken from a form to blob or base64 format, for this, i'm using FileReader of Javascript. My form is this:

```
<form id="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="wizard-big">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Adjuntar Logo *</label>
       <input id="archLogo" name="archLogo" type="file">
   </div>
<form>
```

Ok, my script of javascript is this:

```
<script>
$('#archLogo').change(function() {
   if ($('#archLogo')[0] && $('#archLogo')[0].files[0]) {

       var FR= new FileReader();
       FR.onload = function(e) {
       console.log(e.target.result);
       };       
       FR.readAsDataURL( $('#archLogo')[0].files[0] );
       }
       },false);
</script>
```

The problem is that the console.log is not printing nothing, so, the conversion is not working, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
 if ($('#archLogo')[0] && $('#archLogo')[0].files[0]) 
{
                          var FR= new FileReader();
                          FR.onload = function(e) {
                          logoBlob=e.target.result;
alert(logoBlob);
                          };       
                          FR.readAsDataURL( $('#archLogo')[0].files[0] );
                        }
```

This works

Comment: $('#archLogo'[0])  ≡ $('#')

Comment: you should not use FileReader to display media on a page, use `.src=URL.createObjectURL(file)` to get a fast-loading low-ram URL instead

Comment: @dandavis i know, but I want to see if the image actually becoming a blob format

Comment: not sure i follow, `createObjectURL` needs blobs, so it will verify that as much as a FileReader would... once you fix your minor css selector  typo, either will work...

Comment: Solved the selector error. Right now I'm not interested in displaying the image, I just want to see the generated string